# During the Python subprocess, I do not see anything in the batch file that runs the jar file

Tags: python, subprocess

I have completed the logic to run the batch file in a subprocess and it works.

```
query = 'C:/val/start.bat'
process = subprocess.Popen(query, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The cmd window appears and runs fine, but I do not see any logs that need to be printed.

When I run the batch file directly from Windows, the log is normally generated.

The batch file calls and executes the jar file.

```
@echo off
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Djava.file.encoding=UTF-8 -jar -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m C:\val\val.jar
pause>nul
```

Could you tell me what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Change your process to `process = subproces.Popen(query, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` and running `out, err = process.communicate()` and check what each of those streams shows.

Comment: I checked, but no errors are generated, and it runs normally without logging.

Comment: Strangely, when I call it with os.system, the log is printed normally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the output.

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen('command', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

process.wait()

result = process.stdout.read()
```

Comment: My question is that the progress log is not printed in the cmd window. 
This log appears when I run the batch file directly. 
But when I run subprocess, it does not appear.

Comment: @윤현구 Try adding java to path and use Popen with shell=True and passing the commands in your batch file. `Popen(["java", "-Dfile.encoding=utf-8", ...etc ], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)`

Comment: It does not work from the beginning.
Is it a matter of my commands?
`query = ['java', '-Dfile.encoding=utf-8', '-Djava.file.encoding=UTF-8', '-jar', '-Xms1024m', '-Xmx1024m',  r'C:\val\val.jar']
process = Popen(query, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: Yes, it is. Because when I run the batch file as a subprocess, it works fine.